# window.location.reload(true); doesn't work together with database question

Tags: javascript, php, window.location

I have a countdown script that takes the countdown date from a database. When the countdown is finished the page should reload and then get a new date from the database and then start a new counter. All is working as it should, but after the reload it seems that it doesn't get the time to ask the new question from the database. So the counter just sits at zero on the expired date. I've tried so many different ways to reload the page and none are working.

```
<?php
include '../includes/db.php';

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT gamedate FROM games WHERE gamedate > NOW() ORDER BY gamedate LIMIT 0 , 1 ") or die($conn->error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $gamedate = $row['gamedate'];
}  
?>

<div class="game" data-date="<? echo $gamedate; ?>" id="Countdown"></div>

<script>
  $(".game").TimeCircles({count_past_zero: false},).addListener(countdownComplete);
    
  function countdownComplete(unit, value, total){
    if(total <= 0){
      window.location.reload(true);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Just echo `$gamedate` so it appears in the page. Does it change at all? Does the query work as expected?

Comment: Maybe it's your server caching pages?

Comment: Echo $gamedate just gives the expired date and not a new one from the database. The query works in phpMyAdmin. How to prevent server from caching if it does that?